# MSBuild - Projects with *name to output folder

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to automate the process of some projects output folder, at the moment I'm writing those lines for each project that my website uses:

```
<Target Name="BuildPlugin" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <MSBuild Projects="..\Module.Products\Module.Products.csproj" Targets="Publish" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);PublishDir=$(OutputPath)/plugins/Module.Products" />
  <MSBuild Projects="..\Module.Sales\Module.Sales.csproj" Targets="Publish" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);PublishDir=$(OutputPath)/plugins/Module.Sales" />     
</Target>
```

Is there any way I can automate that to search for Module.* and use in all those places where the name repeats? This is a standalone project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Just make Items and then iterate over them while leveraging their metadata (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-well-known-item-metadata). Something like this (apologies for any mistakes – typing this on a phone).

```
<Target Name="BuildPlugin" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectFiles Include="..\*\*.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <MSBuild Projects="%(ProjectFiles.Identity)" Targets="Publish" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);PublishDir=$(OutputPath)/plugins/%(ProjectFiles.Filename)" />
 </Target>
```

Comment: How would this look for just building a single cs to a different folder than the csproj file? I'm struggling to get msbuild to obey any different output directory for the finished binary, no matter what properties I add to the csproj

Comment: This question involved directing the output of web application projects’ `Publish` target by setting the `PublishDir` property. I would ask a new question and specify the project type, the types of output files and where you are trying to direct them.